# Mono c# web services

Tags: c#, web-services, mono, asmx

I have web services that work great when hosted normally, in Mono I am getting a 500 internal server error first time I tried to run it.

Any idea why it doesn't just work?

The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Error writing request.
  at MY_WebServices.My_Messages.DownloadNewMessages (System.String ID, System.String
        username, System.String password) [0x00000] 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (object,object[])
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr,
        System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000]

Comment: Please provide some code, platform and configuration information.

Comment: You should enable and configure apache mono module. I suggest removing this question and asking on http://serverfault.com. I think you'll get help faster.

Comment: @Mehrdad - stackoverflow is a perfectly acceptable place for this question.  It may not be a server configuration issues.  JL needs to provide more information for us to make that conclusion.

Comment: @JL: Please add a `web-services` tag to such posts, and maybe `asmx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post the error that you are receiving?  Possibilities are that you are using an interface that isn't yet supported in Mono, which there are a couple in the SP2 release of the .NET 2.0 framework, that were specifically put in to support IIS 7.

You also might want to trying running the assembly produced through [MoMA](http://www.mono-project.com/Moma), to check for migration problems.

Comment: MoMA checks out, no problems found there

Comment: Strange, I decided to start problem solving the web method, but its cached somehow, even deleted it from the file, and restarted apache, still the same web method signature exists.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613374/using-asmx-using-lighttpd-and-mono-fastcgi/8131138) discussion about the same problem on nginx to see if can lead you to the right solution.