# using .asmx using lighttpd and mono fastcgi

Tags: asp.net, mono, asmx, lighttpd, xsp

I have deployed a web service to a ubuntu server running lighttpd and fastcgi-mono-server2.  The .asmx page loads correctly but when I test the method I get a 404.

My web service is called Import.asmx and my method is called download and the 404 comes back saying import.asmx/download does not exist

Using xsp2 the same service works perfectly

I assume it is something to do with how the /download gets served by lighttpd/fastcgi but cannot work out how to fix it.

Comment: Hello? Could you please post the method?

Comment: I get the same behaviour when using the sample app provided with the asp.net2-examples package, so it is nothing specifically to do with my method

Answer (score 0):

Solved the 404 error... but now I have a 500.

Actually I was getting this error on every MyService.asmx/SomeMethod post calls. The solution [NOT REALLY] I've figured it out:

```
location ~ \.(aspx|asmx|ashx|asmx\/(.*)|asax|ascx|soap|rem|axd|cs|config|dll)$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9001;
        index index.html index.htm default.aspx Default.aspx;
        fastcgi_index Default.aspx;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
```

I've change it from only *asmx* to *asmx/(*)*. Ok no 404 but now a 500: System.Web.HttpException: Method 'POST' is not allowed when accessing file '/Services/MyService.asmx/MyMethod'.

This findings give me some clues that nginx don't handle properly this kind of requests. After googling for almost 2 hours I've found a [solution](http://techcrawler.riedme.de/2011/02/14/asp-net-ajax-error-405-on-nginx/):

```
location ~ \.asmx(.*) {
             fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.asmx)(.*)$;
             fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
             fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
             fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
             include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
             fastcgi_index Default.aspx;
             fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
     }
```

I wasn't to far from it. Just add this location rule before the current you have and works fine.

Comment: This answer is utterly confusing.  Your first word is "Solved", then in comments you mention having an unsolved error.  You suggest "the solution" followed by "NOT REALLY".  Does your answer actually answer anything?

Comment: It's solves the 404 error. Is the main error related with the question.

Comment: Replacing a 404 error by introducing a 500 error is not a real solution.

Comment: I've found that issue prior to my answer. The solution for the 1st problem might be useful for others. Not a complete solution? That's ok! If someone have the answer that one answer can me accepted as the solution.

Comment: I appreciate that.  If you wouldn't mind cleaning up your answer so it is clear what you are contributing, I will be happy to remove my -1 from your answer.

Comment: Please can you clean up your answer and leave only the parts that actually help the OP. Having all that other solved/not solved stuff in there is confusing, hell, I even wondered at one point if you were the OP with another account. Sorting this would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same issue. Turned out to be default directive for serving 404 when not finding assets. Removed the following line:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

And add `PATH_INFO` as fastcgi param in /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params:

```
fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
```

That fixed it for me. Hope it helps.